# PHP DOM Document copy whole table into a new div

Tags: php, domdocument

I receive HTML table from jquery summernote like this

```
<div class="pasted">
   <table class="table table-bordered" style="width: 100%;">
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td>
              item 1
            </td>
         </tr>
       </tbody>
     </table>
</div>
```

Now i want to convert to this using PHP

```
<div class="pasted">
   <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table table-bordered table-summernote1">
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td>
                 item 1
               </td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
        </table>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here is my PHP Code:

```
<?php

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($text, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

$b = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table');

foreach ( $b as $t )
{
    if ( $t->hasAttributes() )
    {
        foreach ( $t->attributes as $attr )
        {
            $t->removeAttribute($attr->nodeName);
        }

        $t->removeAttribute("style");

        $t->setAttribute('class', 'table table-bordered table-summernote1');

        $responsive  = $dom->createElement('div');
        $t->insertBefore($responsive);
        $responsive->setAttribute('class', 'table-responsive');

        $frag = $t->cloneNode(true);

        $responsive->appendChild($frag);
    }
}

?>
```

PHP code does not work. page hangs on $responsive->appendChild($frag) and processing is never ended.

I have also tried with preg_replace but does not work

```
foreach ( $b as $t )
{
    if ( $t->hasAttributes() )
    {
        foreach ( $t->attributes as $attr )
        {
            $t->removeAttribute($attr->nodeName);
        }

        $t->removeAttribute("style");
    }
}

$text = $dom->saveHTML();

$text = preg_replace('/<table>(.*)<\/table>/isum', '<div class="table-responsive"><table class="table table-bordered table-summernote1">$1</table></div>', $text);
```

It will convert just first 1 or 2 tables. if there are multiple tables, one table goes into another table.

**what is the better solution to solve this?**

Comment: My guess would be that you _cloning_ the table is what messes things up (because once you append this clone, the number of `table` elements change, and since node lists are “live” by definition, that has a huge potential to mess up the foreach loop.) Why are you cloning it in the first place? Do you want this element to exist _twice_ in the resulting document? If not, then just append the original, instead of a clone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be objecting to adding the cloned node inside the node your cloning.  I've changed how `$responsive` is added (to the parent of the table) and remove the `$t` node before adding the clone back in.

```
foreach ( $b as $t )
{
    if ( $t->hasAttributes() )
    {
        foreach ( $t->attributes as $attr )
        {
            $t->removeAttribute($attr->nodeName);
        }

        $t->removeAttribute("style");

        $t->setAttribute('class', 'table table-bordered table-summernote1');

        $responsive  = $dom->createElement('div');
        $t->parentNode->insertBefore($responsive, $t);
        $responsive->setAttribute('class', 'table-responsive');

        $frag = $t->cloneNode(true);
        $t->parentNode->removeChild($t);

        $responsive->appendChild($frag);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Your code works but when there are two tables it generate like:
`<div class="pasted">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
         ...................
    </table>
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-summernote1">
              ...............
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>`

is there any solution? @Niggel

Comment: (Sorry for delay) I've updated the way the new tag is inserted, it now inserts it before the `<table>` tag which is being moved.